# Storybook is giving "Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent" error in angular library

Tags: angular, storybook

Storybook is giving "Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent" with angular 8 library setup

I have already tried adding "import 'core-js/es7/reflect'" in test.ts

Steps to reproduce:

1. ng new demo --createApplication=false
2. ng g library demo -p d
3. npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
4. npm run storybook

getting "Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent" in browser console.

Answer (score 5):

Try downgrading your storybook dependencies 5.1.9 worked for me.

There is probably a bug in @storybook/angular 5.1.10

Comment: Probably there is a bug in the latest @storybook/angular... I have reported an issue to them, will wait for their answer https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7722

Comment: Please add that there might be a bug in that version to your answer

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding "emitDecoratorMetadata": true

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal Your comment helped me thank you! Adding "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in compilerOptions in tsconfig.json resolved the issue.

Comment: It looks like it is fixed but not in the latest release yet. The suggestion in the GitHub issue to run `npx -p @storybook/cli@next sb init --type angular` worked for me with Angular-cli 8.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **"emitDecoratorMetadata": true** to **tsconfig.json** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. "I" cant resolve all parameters for a ts file that holds one of the first @Effects(). But this file is loaded into a module that is loaded into the app module. And I am loading the app module in a story via imports.
The `emitDecoratorMetadata` is set to `true` in both tsconfig files.

```
moduleMetadata({
  imports: [AppModule],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
})
```